# import const array React

Tags: reactjs

I try to import an array into my parent component and send that data as props to his child

```
import Seed from './const/Seed';

export default class ProductList extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const product = Seed.products[0]
    return(
      <div>
        <Product 
        id = {product.id}
        title = {product.title}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and i received an error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

maybe i did not format the right way?
or is there a way to declare a const on a different file?

```
export default class Seed extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const products  = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Yellow Pail',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Green Pail',
      }
    ]
    return products
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The seed file should be :

```
export const products  = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Yellow Pail',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Green Pail',
  },
]

export default {
    products,
}
```

and import them as (and usage as) :

```
import {products} from './const/Seed';
export default class ProductList extends React.Component{
  render() {
    const product = products[0]
    return(
      <div>
        <Product 
        id = {product.id}
        title = {product.title}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`render` method is used to render your content on the browser and not for exporting the constants. Please review react/JavaScript once more