# Passing React props and accessing as ObjectName.ObjectName

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am importing an Array of objects like so `import productData from './productData.js'`.

Where `productData.js` looks something like:

```
var productData = [{}, {}, ...]
module.exports = {productData}
```

However, now within the component expression `TableComponent` to map over the array I have to access it as `productData.productData`. Why is this?

```
const MainBody = () => {
  return (
    <TableComponent productData={productData.values}> </TableComponent>
  );
}

const TableComponent = props => {
  const {productData} = props
  const rows = productData.productData && productData.productData.map((row, index) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        <row>hello</row>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
}
```

Comment: You are exporting product data as an object. Isn't it?

Comment: @VikramThakur, Yes I suppose I am, thank you! So then I am wondering, if I do want to export it as an object, is there a cleaner way to deconstruct the object in a component?

Comment: You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113850/import-const-array-react.

Comment: Thank you very much @VikramThakur that answers everything! If you like  please post as an answer and I’ll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you

```
 import productData from './productData.js'
```

then `productData` is the *default export* of `productData.js`, which is an object, this one:

```
  { productData }
```

and that object has a key `productData` containing the data you want. Now to only export `productData` you got two options:

1) Export `productData` as the default export without wrapping it into an object:

```
 export default productData;
 // or
 module.exports = productData;

 // import as:
 import productData from "./productData";
 // or
 const productData = require("./productData");
```

2) Export `productData` as a named export, then import the named export:

```
 export { productData };
 // or
 module.exports = { productData };

 // import as
 import { productData } from "./productData";
 // or
 const { productData } = require("/.productData");
```

As the file only contains one thing, 1) makes more sense here.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is getting exported as an object, that's why you have to access it as `productData.productData`. To avoid this we can do something like this.

```
// first create an array in product.js file
const productsArray  = [
  {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Yellow Pail',
  },
  {
   id: 2,
   title: 'Green Pail',
  },
]
```

Then you can export it

```
export default { 
  productsArray
}
```